# Перевсти из ISO формата в формат ДД.ММ.ГГГГ, ЧЧ:ММ?

Tags: javascript, дата, date-fns

помогите перевести дату в ISO формате в вид ДД.ММ.ГГГГ, ЧЧ:ММ ( например 22.09.2018, 22:00)

с помощью date-fns ?
https://date-fns.org

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript не мой основной язык, но вроде как можно обойтись стандартными методами:

```javascript
const d = new Date("2018-09-22T22:00:00+0300");
const str = d.toLocaleDateString("ru-RU", { hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit" });
console.log(str);
// Output:
//   "22.09.2018, 22:00"
```